# Looking for suggestions on web hosting solution (Wix, Squarespace, WordPress, for following

Tags: database, wordpress, squarespace, velo, branding

I want to host a clean, branded site that allows users to submit data which I will post process on some regular cadence and send custom emails based on data processing results. I can write code and have extensive experience with AWS, but am looking for the fastest solution.

Any experienced web developers have suggestions of which hosting solution to use? Wix, Squarespace, WordPress. I would prefer Squarespace but am not finding clear documentation stating I can create a form which writes to a database (I.e. DynamoDB, Redshift).

Any suggestions would be great! Thanks!

Comment: The wording of this question is perhaps not the best fit for StackOverflow because the answers are likely to consist primarily of opinion. Consider breaking the question into smaller, more specific ones. For example, "How can a Squarespace form write to an external database such as DynamoDB or Redshift?" Such a question is a better fit for SO since it is more likely to invite answers having to do with capability and methods. It would also (hopefully) give you some information towards your larger context at the same time. More info: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/

Answer (score 1):

Having a good deal of experience with Squarespace, I will address the question *"Is it possible to connect a Squarespace form to a third-party database and, if so, by what means?"*. While I won't address Wix or Wordpress, hopefully it will provide some objective answers and provide some help to your larger context/question.

Squarespace [doesn't support any server-side code](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815358-Custom-code-FAQ); it only supports supports the addition of HTML, CSS and Javascript within [Code Injection](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-Code-Injection), [Code Blocks](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206543167-Using-Code-Blocks), and [Developer Mode](https://developers.squarespace.com/quick-start).

Therefore, your options are:

1. **Send the data client-side with JavaScript.** Write your own HTML form and insert it via code block, markdown block, of developer mode. Then write the corresponding JavaScript to send the data, on submit, to your external database. Alternatively, use a Squarespace form block, prevent the default submission from executing and use your own methods instead.
2. **Connect the Squarespace form block to a Google Sheet and the sheet to the external DB via Apps Script**. [Once connected](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205814638-Managing-form-and-newsletter-storage#toc-google-drive), use Apps Script (set to trigger when a row is added to the sheet) to obtain the submission from the sheet and send it to your external database (similar to [this](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/dynamodb-odbc-mysql-apps-script.rst) or [this](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/dynamodb-odata-gsheets-apps-script.rst), but you'll be going "the other way", sending data to the external DB from Apps Script).
3. **Use Zapier (or similar service) to bridge the gap**, either using [Squarespace's built-in integration](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000641507) or setting up Zapier on your own and setting the Zapier email address [as the email recipient](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205814638-Managing-form-and-newsletter-storage#toc-email-address). You can use Zapier to send form submissions to a new item in DynamoDB, [for example](https://zapier.com/apps/dynamodb/integrations/squarespace). It appears that, at a minimum, you'd have to pay for Zapier as that is a "Premium Integration". For Squarespace, if you were to use their built-in Zapier integration, you'll have to pay for a higher-cost plan (which could be avoided by using the email storage option instead, as mentioned previously).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should choose WordPress, they have a huge documentation, a big community, you can get a ton of support from Wordpress's users when you run into a problem.