# Is it possible to develop a custom backend service in Squarespace?

Tags: squarespace

I need to create a website using **Squarespace** platform. I want to write a backend service calling a third-party API for some metadata.

I looked in their help center, but I found documentation only for JS, HTML and CSS development.

Do you know if it's possible to create such a service and if yes - what language should be used?

Comment: There is some related information that may be of use to you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squarespace [doesn't support any server-side/back-end code](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815928-Adding-custom-code-to-your-site); it only supports the front-end addition of HTML, CSS and Javascript within [Code Injection](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-Code-Injection), [Code Blocks](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206543167-Using-Code-Blocks), and [Developer Mode](https://developers.squarespace.com/quick-start). Therefore, you'd need to use front-end JavaScript development in order to utilize third-party APIs.